# What am I missing with this Apache setup? Getting 408s in the access.log

Tags: apache

I have a bit of a janky setup configured in an attempt to create a little test website that I can navigate to from a source external to my network.  I'm working with a dynamic IP address which obviously isn't ideal, but this page isn't meant to be viewed by anyone.  I'm using DuckDNS to route to my WAN IP, and that allows me to quickly update the dynamicIP that duckDNS points to in a flash when my Dynamic IP refreshes.  I have ports 80 and 443 forwarded on my router to route to my webserver IP.  I have apache configured to listen on ports 80 and 443.

I can hit the website internally from my computer and phone (when its on the network), but when I attempt to hit the site from an external source, I get 408s.  I'm still a little new to apache, so I'm trying to see what I've missed here?  What's weird is that I see the 408s in the access.log - so wouldn't that mean the attempt is at least making it to the webserver?

Comment: Depends upon your setup.  I think some ISP's and maybe even residential routers block those ports so you cannot run your own webserver.

Comment: Yea, this ended up being the issue, actually.  I tunneled to port 80 with ngrok, worked fine.